# ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE error on Edge browser -This site can't be reached might be temporarily down or it may have moved permanently

Tags: .net, iis

I am trying to access a local site hosted on IIS but getting error - ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE. We are in process of updating our certificates, in the mean time we need a workaround.

Is there a way to bypass this error.

Comment: You might run a report to study more about what's wrong with the current certificate, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/ssl-diagnostics.html But there isn't usually a workaround for security related issues. Without a valid certificate, this site won't work in HTTPS.

Comment: The `ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE` error typically indicates an issue with the SSL certificate's key usage. It is not recommended that you bypass the SSL error, usually regenerating the certificate will fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

WORKAOUND is create dword RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled value 0 in HKLM:\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Edge
LONG TERM FIX is to make sure you have good/current SSL Cert cable of modern/non-obsoleted TLS versions and then delete the RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled dword

Comment: This workaround does not seem to do anything.  There is an equivalent registry key for Chrome, but Edge doesn't seem to support it.

Answer (score 0):

we had this same issue on our RDS servers. they all stopped being able to use chrome/edge to get to the rdweb site. We ended up creating a self-signed certificate for them placed it in the trusted root and bound them to the http/s.

Hope that helps.

Comment: how to placed self-signed certificate in the trusted root? I am using IIS

Answer (score 0):

The workaround from Scott worked for me.

Note, you need to reboot after making changes to the Registry.

In my case, I had a service running in IIS with self signed certificate.  My WPF application was unable to connect to the service all of a sudden today.  I tested the service in the Edge browser and noticed it was showing ERR_SSL_KEY_USAGE_INCOMPATIBLE.

I reviewed installed programs and noticed both Edge and Edge WebView2 had been updated today to 121.0.2277.83.  I found recent articles on Microsoft support about this issue, but none mention the workaround from Scott, so I wanted to share my experience with this issue.

To resolve this error in Edge browser, the workaround from Scott worked:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge]
"RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled"=dword:00000000

After a reboot, I was able to communicate with my service in the Edge browser.  However, my WPF application was still unable to connect to the service.  My WPF application uses WebView2, so I tried the workaround in the WebView2 folder:

[HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Edge\WebView2]
"RSAKeyUsageForLocalAnchorsEnabled"=dword:00000000

After another reboot, my WPF application was now able to connect to the service.

I created a stackoverflow account to upvote Scott's answer, but it will not let me upvote or comment; so posting this answer was my only option.